# postfix virtual domain on specific IP address

Tags: linux, email, postfix, virtual-host

We are running `postfix` with single domain (example.com) currently and we have appropriate `PTR` record for that.

Now we want to add one more domain but i want to isolate that domain totally, Even i want to isolate `PTR` record too. so we added new `public` IP address in same server and added `PTR` entry to `abc.com`

1. example.com  -  1.1.1.1
2. abc.com      -  2.2.2.2

How i am going to tell postfix run example.com on `1.1.1.1` ip address and abc.com on `2.2.2.2`

so from outside if someone try to telnet on 25 port he get different appropriate domain for relevant IP.

```
$ telnet mail.example.com 25
Trying ::1...
Connected to mail.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.example.com ESMTP Postfix
```

And for abc.com

```
$telnet mail.abc.com 25
Trying ::1...
Connected to mail.abc.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.abc.com ESMTP Postfix
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following should work for postfix equal or higher than `2.7`.

You need to modify `/etc/postfix/master.cf`, change the line  `smtp inet n - n - - smtpd` to something like this:

```
domain1 unix -       -       n       -       -       smtp
      -o syslog_name=postfix-mail.example.com
      -o smtp_helo_name=mail.example.com
      -o smtp_bind_address=1.1.1.1

domain2 unix -       -       n       -       -       smtp
      -o syslog_name=postfix-mail.abc.com     
      -o smtp_helo_name=mail.abc.com
      -o smtp_bind_address=2.2.2.2
#...
```

Then in `/etc/posfix/main.cf` you will need to remove old transport maps (if any) afterwards add `sender_dependent_default_transport_maps` for exmaple:

```
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_transport
```

In `/etc/postfix/sender_transport` you need to add:

```
@example.com    domain1:
@abc.com    domain2:
#...
```

Then you need to create a hash db from the `sender_transport` file, with command:

```
postmap hash:/etc/postfix/sender_transport
```

Restart postfix to pickup the changes.

You could also move the transport maps to a database and create a table for the domains etc. This is just a basic setup but it should give you some ideas.

Comment: You got it right! does you solution with with `multidomain` senario as well? in case in future i want to add more domain which i want to add in `1.1.1.1` IP where i don't care about `banner` etc.

Comment: I have not tried it, but it should be possible. You could try to add more domains in the sender_tranposrt file, something like `@example.com domain1:`  `@test.com domain1:`  `@anothertest.com domain1:` Although I have not used or not tested it.

Comment: I have checked my version and it is `2.6.6` does above config will work?

Comment: Your config doesn't working when i changed it to thsi and it works! do you know why? `67.111.xxx.xxx:smtp inet n - n - - smtpd -o myhostname=mail.example.com`